# Placing specific point of image on specific point of another c#

Tags: c#, drawimage

I have a image with coordinates `x1,y1`. Lets say `(300,500)`. I want to place there an image 50x50, but not top left corner of that image but `(x2,y2)` of the smaller image. (for example `(20,30)`)

Something like this. I want the two dots to be in the same place
[image]

I tried something like, but this puts my small image below desired point.

```
  bigImage.DrawImage(smallImage, bigImage.x1, bigImage.y1,
    new Rectangle(smallImage.x2, smallImage.y2, smallImage.Height, smallImage.Width),
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Is there a way to do it?

Edit: 
Just realized my solution doesn't work at all, because it crops the image instead of placing it on specified point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you have an `image1` that is placed at `(image1.x, image1.y)`. And you have `image2` that will be placed at `(image2.x, image2.y)`.

Furthermore, there is a target location in `image1`. This target location has coordinates `(image1.target.x, image1.target.y)` inside of `image1`. Let us transform those coordinates to the origin…

Inside `image1` we work on a translated coordinate system. It is offset by `(image1.x, image1.y)`. We need to add that offset. Thus, the position of the target in `image1` relative to the origin is `(image1.x + image1.target.x, image1.y + image1.target.y)`.

Similarly, there is a target location in `image2`. This target location has coordinates `(image2.target.x, image2.target.y)` inside of `image2`. Which means the position of the target in `image2` relative to the origin is `(image2.x + image2.target.x, image2.y + image2.target.y)`.

We want these two targets to be at the same place relative to the origin:

```
(image1.x + image1.target.x, image1.y + image1.target.y)
=
(image2.x + image2.target.x, image2.y + image2.target.y)
```

Let me break that by component:

```
image1.x + image1.target.x = image2.x + image2.target.x
image1.y + image1.target.y = image2.y + image2.target.y
```

We want to archive this by changing the position of `image2`. That is by changing the `image2.x` and `image2.y`. Let us solve the equations for those variables:

```
image2.x = image1.x + image1.target.x - image2.target.x
image2.y = image1.y + image1.target.y - image2.target.y
```

And there is where you must place the second image.

---

Hopefully a picture makes this clearer:

[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand what is ``(image1.x, image1.y)`` and how is it different from ``(image1.target.x, image1.target.y)``

Comment: @MeeraWeeks I meant `(image1.x, image1.y)` to be the position of `image1`. Which would be the position of its top-left corner respect to the origin. On the other hand, I meant `(image1.target.x, image1.target.y)` to be the position that you want to align withing the image. That would be the position of the dot you want to match, respect to the position of the image.

Comment: @MeeraWeeks added picture.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still can't get it to work properly but I think the issue is somewhere else in my calculations. Your explanation cleared up a lot of confusion. Thank you!